# app not working unless there is something in server.js file

Tags: meteor

I have a texting app that I created a while back and broke.  I fixed it by copying all of the code over to another project and installing the same packages.  When I did this, it stopped working and I have no idea why.  I narrowed it down to `texts` returning an empty array since no data is being published.  But in the new app just created, I have the exact same code, but this one is not working...  It happened to me with my other app that I copied from(it did not work, then randomly it started working again) and it worked after a day of not touching it.  And yes, autopublish is installed at version 1.0.7.  Please help this is a reoccuring problem and I really need an answer!

**Client - main.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {Meteor} from "meteor/meteor";
import {Tracker} from "meteor/tracker";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

import {Texts} from "./../imports/api/Text";
import App from "./../imports/ui/App";
import NotFound from "./../imports/ui/NotFound";
import Signup from "./../imports/ui/Signup";
import Login from "./../imports/ui/Login";

Meteor.startup(() => {
    Tracker.autorun(() => {
        let texts = Texts.find().fetch();
        let signedIn = !!Meteor.userId();
        if(signedIn){
          console.log("signed in");
        }else{
          console.log("signed out")
        }
        console.log(texts)
        const routes = (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <App path="/chat" texts={texts}/>
                    <Signup path="/signup" />
                    <Login path="/login" />
                    <Route component={NotFound}/>
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
        ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById("app"));
    });
    console.log("HI")
});
```

**Server - main.js**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  const Texts = new Mongo.Collection("texts") //<--app only works when I put this line of code in the server file
});
```

**Text.js**

```
import {Mongo} from "meteor/mongo";

export const Texts = new Mongo.Collection("texts");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have collection initialized on both client and server. From your code it seems like you're importing `Text.js` from the client code only, that's why it works only when you're creating collection on the server as well. You can import the same `Text.js` in your `server/main.js` and it should work.

Comment: Why would it work if you only import it and not call it in any way?

Comment: Because this import contains `new Mongo.Collection...` instruction. Basically, the same code you have in `server/main.js` in the `startup`.